# I just want to insert data into mysql database php using volley android

Tags: java, android, android-volley

As I'm a beginner. Can anyone help me how to insert data into MySQL database using volley method?  What should I try Volley or Retrofit? Can anyone help me with some example of how to add the data to the MySQL database?

```
String Name,Email,Mobile,DOB;

final EditText name,email,mobile,dob;
Button insert;

name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
mobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobile);
dob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dob);

insert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.insert);

insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Name = name.getText().toString();
            Email = email.getText().toString();
            Mobile = mobile.getText().toString();
            DOB = dob.getText().toString();

            insertdb();
        }

        private void insertdb() {

            final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

// Instantiate the RequestQueue.

RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

String url ="http://ganeshkumar.epizy.com/insertdb.php? 
name="+Name+"&email="+Email+"&mobile="+Mobile+"&dob="+DOB;

// Request a string response from the provided URL.

StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {

// Display the first 500 characters of the response string.

textView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500)); Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

textView.setText("That didn't work!"); Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
            queue.add(stringRequest);

        }
});
```

I Actually don't know how to send the data that I was assigned to the String to the PHP

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Volly please go through this [link](https://www.android-examples.com/volley-post-request-php-mysql/)

You can use Http Post also.. Please refer this [link](https://www.android-examples.com/send-insert-edittext-data-online-to-mysql-db-server-in-android/) 

Please change your php files accordingly